# Vsix installer failing in Visual Studio 2017 (15.3)

Tags: vsix, vsixmanifest

I was getting the error below when installing a self authored Visual Studio extension, that had definitely worked in a previous version of Visual Studio 2017.

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

The relevant excerpt from the log is as follows:

```
19-Dec-16 9:59:50 AM - Searching for applicable products...
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
19-Dec-16 9:59:51 AM - Found installed product - ssms 
19-Dec-1> 9:59:51 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

    at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
```

I would expect to see something more like this

```
3/15/2/17 2:21:54 PM - Searching for applicable products... 
3/15/2017 2:21:54 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
3/15/2017 2:21:54 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
3/15/2017 2:21:54 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
3/15/2017 2:21:54 PM - Found installed product -> Global Location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet searches didn't throw up anything interesting, and I wasn't able to "fix" this as such, but uninstalling Visual Studio and the reinstalling it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check your supported flavours of visual studio in vsix manifest. For v.3 format the right number in the range column is usualy ends with a parenthese, that is the version number is not included in range. Increment this number, rebuild and try to reinstall vsix.